# is there a way to have bash variable automatically updated upon calling?

Tags: bash, variables

I would like to have a bash variable automatically updated. Let's say using a toy example:

```
now=`date`
echo $now
```

Say when I called it, it will be

```
Thu Sep 1 21:20:13 PDT 2016
```

The second time I call it (say using `echo $now`), I want `$now` to be updated to the current time instead of `Thu Sep 1 21:20:13 PDT 2016`, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that purpose create a function that prints the date:

```
now() {
    date
}
```

And use it like this:

```
echo "This message is being printed on $(now)"
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `echo "This message is being printed on $(date)"`?

Comment: Because I think the `date` call is just an example. I don't know what the OP wants...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go around that route, try below:

```
now="eval date"
echo "This message is being printed on $($now)"
```

Comment: The `eval` is completely unnecessary here. Simply `... printed on $(date)"` would avoid the variable, too.

Comment: @tripleee, I am aware of that, and I would have used `$(date)` myself. Since the OP wanted the date printed against that specific variable, I gave this alternative.